# Mapping scalars to a mesh, exporting the result as a vtk file

Tags: python, vtk

I have:

- a MetaImage (`.mha`) file with scalar values and a defined origin, spacing and direction
- a vtk mesh file with triangles where the origin, spacing and direction match

I'm trying to map the scalar values to the mesh, and I'd like to visualize the result in paraview.

Right now, my output only has only 2 different scalars values when it should definitely have more. I know that my input data isn't a problem because I have a software that does the mapping and the result is fine. I want to write this as a script to automatize it and also to start understanding VTK's concepts.

```
In [1]: import vtk
from vtk.util.numpy_support import numpy_to_vtk, vtk_to_numpy

output_file_name = '/tmp/test.vtk'

input_mesh = 'vtk_file.vtk'
input_mha = 'mha_file.mha'

# Read the MHA file (scalars)
reader = vtk.vtkMetaImageReader()
reader.SetFileName(input_mha)
reader.Update()
vtk_image = reader.GetOutput()
scalar_data = vtk_image.GetPointData().GetScalars()

# Read the VTK file (scalars)
reader = vtk.vtkPolyDataReader()
reader.SetFileName(input_mesh)
reader.Update()
polydata = reader.GetOutput()

In [2]: # Getting the number of triangles
n_cells = polydata.GetNumberOfCells()
# Initializing an array with the right shape
cell_data = np.zeros(n_cells)

# Iterating through the triangles and getting the corresponding scalar value
for i in range(n_cells):
    cell = polydata.GetCell(i)
    points = cell.GetPoints()    
    np_pts = np.array([points.GetPoint(i) for i in range(points.GetNumberOfPoints())])
    centroid = np_pts.mean(axis=1)
    centroid_id = vtk_image.FindPoint(centroid)
    value = scalar_data.GetValue(centroid_id)
    cell_data[i] = value

polydata.GetCellData().SetScalars(numpy_to_vtk(cell_data))

Out[2]: 0

In [3]: writer = vtk.vtkPolyDataWriter()
writer.SetFileName(output_file_name)
writer.SetInputData(polydata)
writer.SetScalarsName('a_name')
writer.Write()

Out[3]: 1
```

This `1` as a final output must mean I'm doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out everything I was doing was fine except the triangle centroid computation where it should have been `centroid = np_pts.mean(axis=0)` instead of `centroid = np_pts.mean(axis=1)`